# Push adds array to array instead of elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to get some data from API and store it in array. If I set value to it as assigning through = the returned data is displayed as I need. But if I use push to add elements they are added as another array.

It is console log of array after first assigning `this.elements = response.data`

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(3)
0: {ID: 40, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:09.769066+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:09.769066+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
1: {ID: 39, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:06.779473+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:06.779473+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
2: {ID: 38, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:01.738319+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:01.738319+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

And it is through push method `this.elements .push(response.data)`

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: Array(3)}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(4)
0: {ID: 40, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:09.769066+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:09.769066+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
1: {ID: 39, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:06.779473+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:06.779473+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
2: {ID: 38, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:01.738319+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:01.738319+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
3: Array(3)
0: {ID: 38, created_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:01.738319+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T22:15:01.738319+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
1: {ID: 33, created_at: "2021-03-13T10:59:06.521453+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T10:59:06.521453+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
2: {ID: 32, created_at: "2021-03-13T10:58:59.111903+03:00", updated_at: "2021-03-13T10:58:59.111903+03:00", DeletedAt: null, user_id: 19, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

How can I add elements of the array instead of the array itself?

Comment: `el.push(...arr)` will do

Comment: Or traditional method of `Array.prototype.push.apply(this.elements, response.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use spread operator to concatenate the original array with the new one :

```
this.elements =[...this.elements, ...response.data]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `push` with spread operator:

```
this.elements.push(...response.data)
```

E.g.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [12, 13, 14];
arr1.push(...arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```